# What part of my code is in the event dispatch queue

Tags: java, swing, event-handling

I thought I understood EDQ until I hit this problem.    I have the code shown below.   It reads from a Bufferred reader.   If the first character received is a "Z" I execute one set of code (displaying a JOptionPane) and if it is a 0 I execute another section of code (displaying another JOptionPane).   I am trying to do this within the EDQ and so I use SwingUtilities invokeAndWait.   When I test these error conditions, the first statement in the conditional works as designed, but I get a java error when testing the else clause.  Specifically:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.lang.Error: Cannot call invokeAndWait from the event dispatcher thread
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(Unknown Source)

It is all part of the same conditional.   How can one clause be part of the EDQ and another clause not be.

This is crazy.

Thanks for any help.

Elliott

```
     while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.charAt(0) == 'Z') {
            String theMsg;
            theMsg = "No records were found.";
            try {
                SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new DoShowDialog(null, theMsg, 0));
            } catch (java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
            noDocs = true;
            Object args[] = new Object[1];
            args[0] = "1";
            window.call("uploadConfig", args);
            downloadAccount.setEnabled(true);
            uploadAccount.setEnabled(false);
            deleteAllUnselectedCodes.setEnabled(false);
            queue = null;
            if (poll) {
                polltimer.restart();
            }
        } else if (line.charAt(0) == 'O') {
            String theMsg;
            theMsg = "Account is currently checked out 
            by user "+ line.substring(1)
            + ".  You can view this 
            account but you cannot modify it. ";
            try {
                SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new DoShowDialog(null, theMsg, 0));
            } catch (java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
            initialckBoxState = false;
            accountfoundandnotcheckedout = true;
            viewMode = true;
            patientpane.setEditFields(false);
            otherpane.setEditFields(false);
            getAccountImages(acctEntered); // bluenoble
        }
        .....................
        more stuff
    }
```

Comment: Typically it's referred to as the "EDT" not "EDQ" ; )   Anyway, I don't know if there are any guarantees as to *from* which thread the calls shall be made in the rest of your code but you can work around your problem easily: anytime you need to call a method which must absolutely (or must not) be called from the EDT, you can call *SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()* to verify if you're on the EDT or not...

Comment: What line throws the exception? Are you trying to manipulate Swing components off of the EDT (with your setEditFields and similar method calls)?  Can you isolate the error and create and post an [sscce](http://sscce.org)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Execution doesn't jump threads.

Thus *all the code posted runs in the EDT* (Event Dispatch Thread) and it refuses to `invokeAndWait` because that causes an inherent deadlock. (Actually, it could be turned into an invoke-immediate as done with SynchronizationContexts in .NET, but it was not designed as such.)

In this particular case I suspect the code is invoked from *within* an EDT callback (and copy'n'pasted from another scenario). The "trivial fix" (that would eliminate this exception) would be to eliminate the `invokeAndWait` methods, but that will have a negative impact if this code is invoked off the EDT as well -- the two situations much be handled differently. Take some time to determine *when/where* this code will run, and why.

As others have pointed out, this code seems confused: if it's *off* the EDT, manipulating Swing objects is bad, and if it's *on* the EDT then there is no need to `invokeAndWait` and blocking is bad.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

if that is eventually called from a event handler then it is called from the EDT (all your code will be unless you use swingworkers or explicitly create thread/use threadpools)

check the stack trace to find were it comes from

to fix it use aforementioned [SwingWorker](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) and override doInBackground() and you can check whether you are in the dispatch thread with [`SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#isEventDispatchThread%28%29)

Comment: Are you suggesting that the same section of call may or may not be called from the EDT?   It seems to suggest that it is kind of a hit or miss thing.

Comment: @Elliott yes any function can be called from any active thread check the call hierarchy of the method (there's a tool for that in eclipse) in which the section resides to see the possible places (and threads) that it can be invoked from

Answer (score 1):

1) theMsg look like crazy `theMsg = "someString" + localVariable + "anotherString"`

2a) why did you call Swing GUI inside Basic File I/O

2b) why did you build GUI inside Basic File I/O

read File, close(); I/O Stream in finally block

3) you create lots of DoShowDialog(null, theMsg, 0));, every loop create one, and etc

4) every true and false move outside this I/O Stream

5) load every events to the some of Array, if I/O Stream

6) you code probably freeze GUI, if exist

7) move all Stream to the BackGround Task